# Thumbnail image not displayed in ebay sandbox

Tags: php, ebay-api

I put picture details in request xml while adding products in ebay using additem call of Trading API in this format

```
<PictureDetails>
<PictureURL>http://www.mysite.com/images/11.jpg</PictureURL>
</PictureDetails>
```

It is not displaying thumbnail while listing products but the image is displayed in product detail page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ebay sandbox does not support thumbnails/gallery images as mentioned in the ebay forum: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/231/~/gallery-images-in-the-sandbox